# Limit PHP foreach Results

Tags: php, foreach

I have a section in my footer from a script, that I am trying to customize and that displays the website categories.

Currently the results were limited to 9 results per column and continuing onto x amounts of columns. I need to be able to stop at 2 columns.

Here is the code I have

```
<div class="left">
    <h3 style="padding-top:15px;"><?php echo BROWSE_CATEGORIES; ?></h3>
    <?php $footer_category= $this->home_model->get_category(); ?>
    <?php if($footer_category) { $ftr_cnt=1; ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($footer_category as $cat) { 
            echo '<li>'.anchor('search/category/'.$cat->project_category_id,substr($cat->project_category_name,0,30)).'</li>'; 

            if($ftr_cnt>9) { $ftr_cnt=1; echo "</ul><ul>";  }
                $ftr_cnt++;
            }
        } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: is there any reason that you can't change `$ftr_cnt>9` to `$ftr_ctn>2`?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `break` when you've reached `9 * 2`, where 2 is the amount of columns you want.

```
$ftr_cnt = 1;
foreach($footer_category as $cat) 
{ 
    echo '<li>'.anchor('search/category/'.$cat->project_category_id,substr($cat->project_category_name,0,30)).'</li>'; 
    if($ftr_cnt == 9) 
    { 
        echo "</ul><ul>";  
    } 

    $ftr_cnt++;

    if($ftr_cnt >= (9 * 2))
    {
        echo "</ul>";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input.

No matter how i insert this it breaks the page ;( all i get is a blank page.

Comment: @Shadowtek, can you check your error logs? I don't see an error right now. Maybe there is a conflict somewhere?

Comment: @Shadowtek try to debug a bit, remove some parts until you get it working again, then you should know what the problem is. For instance, try removing the `anchor` and replacing it with just some text.

Comment: Rune Thank you once again for your help, i have managed to get the code in with out the page breaking however it has has no effect. I will keep trying :)

Comment: @Shadowtek try to echo every `$ftr_cnt` after increasing it. Then do an echo in both `if` statements. If everything echoes correctly then it's something with that anchor part.